# External Drive works on windows but not ubuntu

Tags: drive

So ive had this drive for years working fine. today i was using it to transfer files from my windows machine to ubuntu and suddenly ubuntu wouldnt recognize it anymore.

it wont show up in disks either. still works fine on windows.
ive looked at some of the solutions on here but not are working for me so far.

any help would be great

Comment: Its file system shows its NTFS on windows

Answer (score 1):

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?

The Windows "Fast Boot" setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: thnks ill check this out. Its possible. it did do an update while i had the drive in. After trying it 100 times it all of a sudden worked on ubuntu again.

Comment: @boreal, there is no "mystery" here: just make sure your file system is healthy and "clean" (i.e., fully closed) before connecting it to a Linux system.